# C++: How to define a data member as const

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the the class bellow. I want the ROI variable to  be a `const` member

```
class MiniPatch
{
private:
    cv::Mat mimOrigPatch;                                           // Original pixels
    cv::Rect roi; <---- I want it to be const                                               
    int rows;
    int cols;

public:
    MiniPatch(){}
    MiniPatch(cv::Point2i irPos, const cv::Mat &image);
    static const int mnHalfPatchSize = 4;                           // How big is the patch?
};
```

the implementation of the constructor is as follow:

```
MiniPatch::MiniPatch(cv::Point2i irPos, const cv::Mat & image)
{
  assert(pointInImageRange(image, irPos, mnHalfPatchSize));                             
  roi = cv::Rect(cv::Rect(0, 0, 2 * mnHalfPatchSize + 1, 2 * mnHalfPatchSize + 1));     
  rows = roi.height;
  cols = roi.width;

  cv::Rect region;

  region = roi + irPos - cv::Point2i(irPos.x - roi.width / 2, irPos.y - roi.height / 2); 
  mimOrigPatch = cv::Mat(region.height, region.width, CV_8UC1);                          //define the patch
    image(region).copyTo(mimOrigPatch);                                                  //crop and copy to patch image

}
```

My question is: **How can I define this roi variable such that it's a `const` member?**

thanks

Comment: I'm curious. How is it that you know enough about const to use it on the constructor parameter but not on the member variable?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I define this roi variable such that it's a const member?

You declare it as a `const` member if `MiniPatch`:

```
class MiniPatch
{
  // as before
  ...

  const cv::Rect roi;
};
```

Once initialized, a `const` instance cannot be changed. Therefore, unless a default initialization suffices, you need initialize it in the constructor initialization list:

```
MiniPatch::MiniPatch(cv::Point2i irPos, const cv::Mat& image)
: roi( /* ctor arguments*/)
{
  rows = roi.height;
  cols = roi.width;
  cv::Rect region ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: I did this right now... It's not working! I get the following: ` error: non-static const member `const Rect MiniPatch::roi', can't use default assignment operator`

Comment: @PhonoDots Your class has a `const` data member. You cannot assign to a `const` object, so your class is non assignable. That is to be expected. And you can certainly not assign anything to `roi`, because it is `const`.

Comment: @DieterLücking and why? Surely OP knows how to construct this object.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking, I don't understand you... Can you explain your answer a bit more. Thanks

Comment: @Jefffrey Fine, I still don't see why I should explicitly put in the constructor arguments. I have told OP what they need to know to achieve what they asked for.

Comment: @juanchopanza, the comment was rude towards the OP so I removed it. But I wasn't saying you should put the constructor arguments. I was just saying that the OP seems completely lost. Your answer looks fine to me, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

A const member needs direct initialization (ctor-initializer):

```
typedef int CvRect;
class MiniPatch
{
private:
    const CvRect roi; // Your cv::Rect

public:
    MiniPatch()
    :   roi(1) // Replace 1 by: 0, 0, 2 * mnHalfPatchSize + 1, 2 * mnHalfPatchSize + 1
    {}
};
```

However, the 'const cv::Rect roi: is always the same in your context and could be a static member or result of a inline member function 'static cv::Rect roi() const'.